# SQL query help: Need to check for multiple strings being present in one field

Tags: sql

Example data of employees database, Column: Positions >>>

1. Director of marketing
2. director
3. Marketing director
4. Sales manager
5. Sales Director

Need help with  a query which will filter all contact rows that have the text strings "Market" and "director" in column positions. So if I were to run it through the example data, rows 1 and 3 would be returned.

MY solution so far:

```
    WHERE (employees.position LIKE '%Market%' AND employees.position LIKE '%director%')
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing this code, since I'd also like to add other position prefixes like "head of" and "vice president".

```
    WHERE (employees.position LIKE '%Market%' AND (employees.position LIKE '%director%' OR employees.position LIKE '%vice president%' OR employees.position LIKE '%head of%'))
```

Again is there an easier way of writing this?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, to make things clearer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a simple list of OR criteria not AND.

If you want both anyone who is ex: Market OR is a Director, they could be individually true, or both true.  Now you want president and head of too... all consider individually...

```
where
      employees.position like "%Market%"
   OR employees.position like "%Direct%"
   OR employees.position like "%vice president%"
   OR employees.position like "%head of%"
```

Now, for the condition that someone is a "Marketing Director", they would be qualified under two of the criteria instead of just one.  The others in similar, as long as someone is in the classification you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
declare @filter varchar(1000)
set @filter=',director,vice president,head of,'
SELECT ........
WHERE (employees.position LIKE '%Market%' AND 
(
@fliter like '%,'+employees.position+',%'
)
```